# navigationBarItems position inconsistency when a button hidden

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Suppose we have following navigationBarItems for a NavigationView with operational editMode environment in SwiftUI:

```
@Environment(\.editMode) var mode

...

.navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
            if mode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
            EditButton()
        }
)
```

the position of trailing navigation bar items wont return back to original position after the first editMode activation, these are screenshots (right edge of iPad in simulator):

[image: first init]

then, activate the edit mode

[image: activate edit mode]

so far behave as expected, but when we toggle deactivate, this is what happened:

[image: Edit button shifted]

Notice that the Edit button shifted to the left, is there a way to fix this? is this expected behaviour ? I expect it to be like the first picture when editMode deactivated

Answer (score 0):

I've reported this as a bug to Apple. It appears that the HStack is not resizing itself when you reduce the number of items in it. Therefore, the single remaining button is centered in the space that was occupied by the previous 2 buttons.

Was not fixed in Xcode 12.0 beta 2

Answer (score 0):

The solution if a bit hacky but it solves this unwanted issue.

I used a private state :

```
@State private var bug: Bool = false
```

(and you call `self.bug = false` whenever it is needed (for example `.onAppear{...}`)
And do not forget to do `self.bug = true` when the edit button was tapped...)

And thanks to this state you can put a conditional offset to the edit button :

```
.offset(x: self.bug ? 30 : 0)
```